# SqlAlchemy add tables versioning to existing tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Imagine that I have one table in my project with some rows in it.

For example:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlalchemy as sa

from app import db

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    content = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
```

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy, so db.session is scoped session object.
I saw in https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/versioned_history/history_meta.py
but i can't understand how to use it with my existing tables and anymore how to start it. (I get `ArgumentError: Session event listen on a scoped_session requires that its creation callable is associated with the Session class.` error when I pass `db.session` in versioned_session func)

From versioning I need the following:

1) query for old versions of object

2) query old versions by date range when they changed

3) revert old state to existing object

4) add additional info to history table when version is creating (for example editor user_id, date_edit, remote_ip)

Please, tell me what are the best practicies for my case and if you can add a little working example for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around that error by attaching the event handler to the `SignallingSession` class[1] instead of the created session object:

```py
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SignallingSession
from history_meta import versioned_session, Versioned

# Create your Flask app...

versioned_session(SignallingSession)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Article(Versioned, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    content = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
```

The sample code creates parallel tables with a `_history` suffix and an additional `changed` datetime column. Querying for old versions is just a matter of looking in that table.

For managing the extra fields, I would put them on your main table, and they'll automatically be kept track of in the history table.

[1] Note, if you override `SQLAlchemy.create_session()` to use a different session class, you should adjust the class you pass to `versioned_session`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're running into this bug: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/182

One workaround would be to stop using flask-sqlalchemy and configure sqlalchemy yourself.